# Add field 'x' to class if input object has property 'x'

Tags: typescript

Suppose I have a class EventCard which takes an object containing some properties. One of these fields (in the class) is optional.

```
const onCardChangeEvent = function(newCard) {
  if (newCard["choices"]) {
    currentChosenCard.value = new EventCard({
      name: newCard.name,
      event: newCard.event,
      cardType: newCard.cardType,
      description: newCard.description,
      choices: newCard.choices
    });
  } else {
    currentChosenCard.value = new EventCard({
      name: newCard.name,
      event: newCard.event,
      cardType: newCard.cardType,
      description: newCard.description
    });
  }
};
```

Can I boil this code down to just the class instantiation instead of checking if the "choices" property exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using a combination of ES6 object destructuring and then constructing the payload whose `choices` property conditionally exists? In that sense you can avoid a lot of code duplication:

```
const onCardChangeEvent = function({ name, event, cardType, description, choices }) {

    const payload = {
        name,
        event,
        cardType,
        description
    };

    if (choices)
        payload.choices = choices;

    currentChosenCard.value = new EventCard(payload);
};
```

Comment: It looks like @EdwinCarlsson could shorten it to just
`const onCardChangeEvent = (payload) => { currentChosenCard.value = new EventCard(payload); }`
unless there are fields in `payload` that should *not* be sent to the EventCard constructor.